# Why can only humans dual-class and only demihumans multiclass?

Tags: multi-classing, races, adnd-2e, lore

Is there an in-game explanation as to why some races can multi-class and others can dual-class? For example, is there an explanation in an article or book somewhere saying that *It's the will of the gods* or whatever that a half-elf can be a druid/ranger and an elf can't?

I am aware (of and unconcerned with) the *game balance* concerns raised by the *Player's Handbook*. I know about those. I'm looking for narrative reason rather than a mechanical one.

Comment: [Related points in this answer about designer vision](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8027/22566)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of old-school D&D class level limitations?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8017/what-is-the-purpose-of-old-school-dd-class-level-limitations)

Answer (score 8):

The *Player's Handbook* (1989) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition*  says

> The human race has one special ability:… Humans can choose to be of any class… and can rise to great level in any class. The other races have fewer choices of character classes and usually are limited in the level they can attain. These restrictions reflect the natural tendencies of the races (dwarves like war and fighting and dislike magic, etc.).…
>
> The limits also exist for play balance.… The demihuman races have other powers that make them entertaining to play—including the ability to be multi-classed…. (20)

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* (1993) for *Advanced Dungeons and Dragons, 2nd Edition*  says

> [H]umans are more motivated, indeed, driven by ambition and the desire for power, than the demihuman races. Thus, they advance further and more quickly than others.…
>
> Demihuman characters are limited in how high a level they can achieve both to preserve internal consistency (humans are more flexible than non-humans) and to enforce game balance. (14)

#### Conclusion

So the ability to multi-class is, in essence, paid for *mechanically* through demihuman class and level limits and justified *narratively* by saying that humans possess greater ambition and drive than demihumans. This can be lumped together: human drive limits humans to dual-classing rather than multi-classing because humans throw their all into things.

(Going into this, I'd thought at the time that the humans' short lifespans were part of the the reason that they couldn't multi-class, but that detail's absent from the *Dungeon Master's Guide* and goes unmentioned in the entries for shorter-lived races in the *Complete Book of Humanoids*.)

Comment: Nothing like this appears in the PHB nor the DMG. The PHB at p.20 talks only about *level limits* reflecting the tendencies of races (narrative justification) and how it improves play balance. Each race's description discusses *which* MC options they have (usually around para. 4), but nothing as to *why* (in-game). The multi- and dual-class sections (pp.44-45) just describe the mechanics, with flavorful worked examples that don't address in-universe reasons. The DMG says nothing about multiclassing.

Comment: @nitsua60... Yes, you appear to be correct; I was recalling the level limits and lumping them with the multi-classing restrictions that they paid for.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any in-game narrative reasons for these limitations, and quite frankly, I would be surprised if any existed.  For one thing, if there were narrative reasons for the limitations, then that would be something the setting(s) would have needed to address when the limitations were removed in later editions of the game and - again, to my knowledge - there was no such *in-game* upheaval about various races suddenly learning to multi-class.

Not within the scope of your question, but I think this is just a byproduct of the game evolving over time.  The earliest editions of D&D had non-human races as Classes with specific, proscribed roles.  Then AD&D came along and created a division between Race and Class, subject to some limitations.  Later editions removed these entirely, and the previously subjugated masses rejoiced.

Comment: I think you sorely underestimate how much ink was spilled on these and other topics in early D&D; I'd bet money there's something specifically from Gygax or Lakofka in Draon about this.

Comment: I've never seen anything in the many many years of playing and reading about 2e.

Comment: Of particular note is that the OD&D elf was effectively a fighter/mage.  I think the OD&D halfling may have been a fighter/thief, but I'm not so certain on that one.

Comment: @BenBarden you are correct. And a dwarf was just a short fighter, iirc.